# sql conditional logic to check for a value in one or more tables sql developer

Tags: sql, if-statement, package, conditional-statements, database-administration

lets say, I have a page that displays:

```
******* Header1 ************
ColumnA columnB  columnC    columnD
value1**V**  123       1234      12345
value1**VA**  123       1234      12345
value1**V**  123       1234      12345
```

so back to the sql developer now.
if you look at the colA, it has values ending with V and/or VA.
V and VA are stored in 2 different values.
So here's my question now:
how would I retrieve its parent id from its own respective table?

so in the query ill have to process, if the colA has/is ending with V, then go to the V table and get its corresponding value (which in our case its value1V, id from the V table).
is this scenario possible?
if so, how?
any help is greatly appreciated.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a bit of detail missing from your question, but if I've understood you correctly, I think you want to return a value from one of two tables depending on whether ColumnA contains 'VA' or just 'V'.

In this case I would join to both the tables, then in the select clause, use a **case when** and **like** to choose which column from which table is returned.

I have provided a rough example below as I don't have the details. I have also used left outer joins in my rough example, another type of join may be more suitable in your case.

```sql
SELECT [ColumnA]
,[ColumnB]
,[ColumnC]
,[ColumnD]

,CASE WHEN [ColumnA] LIKE '%V**' THEN V.[ColumnA] ELSE VA.[ColumnA] END AS [ParentID]


FROM [Table] AS [A]

LEFT OUTER JOIN [Table V] AS [V]
ON A.[ColumnA] = V.[ColumnA]

LEFT OUTER JOIN [Table VA] AS [VA]
ON A.[ColumnA] = VA.[ColumnA]
```